# I want to update my listbox but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to retreive the data in Form2 to but it show me nothing in the Form2:
When i click the update button it just show me Blank Form2:

Form1 I am doing:

```
ProductList products = new Prod
          private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int i = this.lstPerson.SelectedIndex;
            Product product = products[i];
            Form2 frmUpdate = new Form2();
            product = frmUpdate.GetNewProduct();
            products[i] = product;
            products.Add(product);
            FillProductListBox();
        }


    private void FillProductListBox()
    {
        lstPerson.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Product p in products)

            lstPerson.Items.Add(p.GetDisplayText("\t"));

    }
```

In Product Class:

```
             public class Product
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string email;

    public Product()
    {
    }

    public Product(string firstname, string lastname, string email)
    {
        this.Firstname = firstname;
        this.Lastname = lastname;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get
        {
            return firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
        }
    }

    public string Lastname
    {
        get
        {
            return lastname;
        }
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return email;
        }
        set
        {
            email = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string  GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return Firstname + sep + Lastname + sep + Email;
    }

}
```

In Book Class:
           private double assessmentGrade;
        private double assignmentGrade;

```
    public Book()
    {
    }

    public Book(string firstname, string lastname, double assessmentGrade,double assignmentGrade,
        string email) : base(firstname, lastname, email)
    {
        this.AssessmentGrade = assessmentGrade;
        this.AssignmentGrade = assignmentGrade;
    }

    public double AssignmentGrade
    {
        get
        {
            return assignmentGrade;
        }
        set
        {
            assignmentGrade = value;
        }
    }


    public double AssessmentGrade
    {
        get
        {
            return assessmentGrade;
        }
        set
        {
            assessmentGrade = value;
        }
    }


    public override string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return base.GetDisplayText(sep) + " (" + AssessmentGrade + ")" + AssignmentGrade;
    }
```

And In same as Software class.

In Form2

```
private Product product = null;

    public Product GetNewProduct()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
        return product;
    }


                 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidData())
        {
            if (rbBook.Checked)
                product = new Book(txtName.Text, txtLName.Text,
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtAssessGrade.Text), Convert.ToDouble(txtAssigGrade.Text), txtEmail.Text);
            else
                product = new Software(txtName.Text, txtLName.Text,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtAssessGrade.Text), txtEmail.Text);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

I doesn't show me any thing it just add the more data in listbox not update the data and not retrieving the data in Form2.Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Can you show the code more code of Form2 ? What else do you have in Form2 please update your question and give more code from Form2.

Comment: are you passing product to form2 or form2 gets product itself?

Comment: It seems to me that you return nuul all the time from Form2. In Form2 you are doing product = null; then rreturn it . Then you put the null in Form1 product. You wrote that you try to retrive the data in Form2 but what data is that ? Can you point us in Form2 code what data did you try to get ? Is that all the code in Form2 ?

Comment: you don't have to call close(). Set btnSave DialogResult property to DialogResult.OK

Comment: Did you use a breakpoint inside the btnSave_Click ? Put a breakpoint on the if(IsValidData()) and see if rbBook is realy checked i guess its a checkBox and then see what all the txtName Lname txtEmail contian. If i understand it right you first click on the button in Form2 and then click on the button in Form1 to retrive the data right ?

Comment: can yo show us FillProductListBox()?

Comment: You have to call initializeComponent() in the constructor of form2.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in Form2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Product product = null;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Product GetNewProduct()
    {
        return product;
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidData())
        {
            if (rbBook.Checked)
            {
                product = new Book(txtName.Text, txtLName.Text,
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtAssessGrade.Text), Convert.ToDouble(txtAssigGrade.Text), txtEmail.Text);
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidData()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//Modify in Form1:



       public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                private ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {


                    Form2 frmUpdate = new Form2();
                    frmUpdate.ShowDialog();
                    Product product = frmUpdate.GetNewProduct();
                    products.Add(product);
                    FillProductListBox();

                }
                private void FillProductListBox()
                {
                    lstPerson.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (Product p in products)

                        lstPerson.Items.Add(p.GetDisplayText("\t"));

                }    
            }
```

Comment: its just adding the value not updating the first value..:(

Comment: FillProductListBox() proves useful

Comment: I understand it now. It is working perfectly for me. You are missing initializeComponent() in Form2.Check the revised code.